# C# Binary reading incomplete strings

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, binaryreader

i was hoping to get some help on this problem, so as you can see in the picture bellow, i can't seem to read the whole word up to 0x00:
[image]

what i am trying ot do, is to just read the file strings properly ,here is the code i used to open the file:

```
        private void menuItem2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listView1.Items.Clear();
        textBox1.Text = "";
        menuItem12.Text = "file type is: ";
        OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
        ofd.Title = "Open File";
        ofd.Filter = "All Files (*.*)|*.*";
        if (ofd.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            path = ofd.FileName;
            BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(File.OpenRead(path), Encoding.GetEncoding("SHIFT-JIS"));
            foreach (char mychar in br.ReadChars(4)) menuItem12.Text += mychar;
            if (menuItem12.Text != "file type is: TXTD")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("This is not a TXTD file...", "Sorry", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                    MessageBox.Show("File opened Succesfully!", "Info", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                    br.BaseStream.Position = 0x8;
                    int Pntrnum = br.ReadInt16();
                    menuItem11.Visible = true;
                    menuItem11.Text = Pntrnum.ToString();
                    List<int> offsets = new List<int>();
                    br.BaseStream.Position = 0x10;
                    for (int i = 0; i < Pntrnum; i++)
                    {
                        offsets.Add(br.ReadInt32());
                    }
                    Dictionary<int, string> values = new Dictionary<int, string>();
                    for (int i = 0; i < offsets.Count; i++)
                    {
                        int currentOffset = offsets[i];

                        int nextOffset = (i + 1) < offsets.Count ? offsets[i + 1] : (int)br.BaseStream.Length;

                        int stringLength = (nextOffset - currentOffset - 1) / 2;

                        br.BaseStream.Position = currentOffset;

                        var chars = br.ReadChars(stringLength);
                        values.Add(currentOffset, new String(chars));
                    }

                    foreach (int offset in offsets)
                    {
                        listView1.Items.Add(offset.ToString("X")).SubItems.Add(values[offset]);
                    }

                    br.Close();
                    br = null;
            }
        }
        ofd.Dispose();
        ofd = null;
    }
```

Comment: In `stringLength = (nextOffset - currentOffset - 1) / 2`, why do you divide by 2? (I think that the "SHIFT-JIS" encoding has single-byte chars in the ASCII range).

Comment: thank you sir, didn't see it there, please post it as a solution so i can pick it :) thank you again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "SHIFT-JIS" encoding uses single bytes for characters in the ASCII range.

I can see that your text is ASCII, but this line of code:

```
stringLength = (nextOffset - currentOffset - 1) / 2;
```

is assuming that the characters are occupying two bytes.

Answer (score 1):

In order to convert binary data to proper string you should know about **[Encodings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5864272/understanding-text-encoding-in-net)**. So you can find some useful encodings in `System.Text.Encoding`. Then you can convert byte array to string like this:

```
byte[] byteArray = // your byte array
System.Text.Encoding encoding = Encoding.UTF8; //use proper encoding
string value = encoding.GetString(byteArray);
```

Also you can see the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)