# preserve special characters when writing all lines to text file

Tags: c#, file-io, special-characters, file.readalllines

I have a few lines that contain special characters like these lines:

> CommunautéFinancièreAfricaineBEACFranc(XAF)
>   CommunautéFinancièreAfricaineBCEAOFranc(XOF)

But, when I write those lines into a text file, I get this as a result:

> CFACommunaut�Financi�reAfricaineBEACFranc
>   CFACommunaut�Financi�reAfricaineBCEAOFranc

This is how I write the lines:

`File.WriteAllLines(@"c:\file5.txt", lines);`

I also tried the 3rd parameter of `File.WriteAllLines()` by passing an `Encoding`. But that didn't help either.

`File.WriteAllLines(@"c:\file5.txt", lines, Encoding.UTF8);`
`File.WriteAllLines(@"c:\file5.txt", lines, Encoding.ASCII);`

This is how I read all lines:

```
File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\file4.txt").ToList()
        .ForEach(g => 
            lines.Add(g.ToString()
            .Replace("/", string.Empty)
            .Replace("(", string.Empty)
            .Replace(")", string.Empty))
        );
```

The crazy thing is, the characters are displayed perfectly fine in another text file (file4.txt) where I read everything in.

Comment: You're on the right rack with the encoding, I think.  Not sure which one you need, but it should be one that handles those special characters.

Comment: I'm tempted to close this as a duplicate (e.g. /questions/1025332/determine-a-strings-encoding-in-c-sharp or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5864272/understanding-text-encoding-in-net). All you have to do is understand what an encoding is, and find the correct one.

Comment: How do you obtain the result? Is your text file editor Unicode-aware?

Comment: @CodeCaster, it's just notepad. I don't know if it's unicode aware.

Comment: @Tim, i've tried them all, but I find it very strange that from one text file all is fine, to the other text file where I get this result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notepad does not recognize UTF-8 unless you add a BOM.

You have three choices:

1. Decide notepad is dumb and ignore the issue. Better editors will recognize UTF-8.
2. Add a BOM. Use `var utf8WithBom = new Utf8Encoding(true, true)` as second argument.
3. Use the legacy encoding. Specify `Encoding.Default` as second argument.

   The resulting file will corrupt characters not present in the current code page. It won't display correctly on systems using in certain other countries.

   IMO this one is a bad idea, but I still mention it for completeness.

Comment: It had to do something with BOM. I eventually converted the text from ANSI (IIRC) to utf8 with BOM. I did this conversion with notepad++ via Encoding menu.